# How do I apply a skeleton rig to multiple objects?

Tags: rigging

I have 15 total parts and I thought that the rig skeleton fits with the multiple objects. So I tried to look up information online. No luck. So this might be a nooby question and may be closed as too broad but, how do you apply a rig to multiple parts? Please be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a valid question.

If you mean your model is made of ***multiple meshes***, select all of the meshes, then *lastly*, select the bone, and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and choose your favorite option. Maybe `with automatic weights`.

*You can have **any number** of meshes paired to a bone, but you must **select the bone last,** before pairing.* I actually prefer this method when working with meshes that should not be distorted by bone movement, like a mechanical robot. Each piece that should only twist and move, not bend, I parent to an individual bone separately. *It works to parent them one by one as well.*

***Tip:*** You can also select all of the meshes and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to join them, if that is the desired result. You may want to apply modifiers before joining though.

If you mean that you have ***multiple different models*** that can all use the *same bones* and animations, then pair the first object, then the second, then the third, all in the same way.

- First, pair one of the objects you would like paired. Most likely this will be using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and choose your favorite option. Maybe `with automatic weights`.
- Now select the second object, then the bone. Repeat the process of pairing by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and choose your favorite option.

Now if you select the skeleton and go to pose mode, you will find that both meshes will move along with the bone.

***Tip:*** To make things simpler, you may wish to move your skeleton to one layer, and each model to another layer. That way you can pose the skeleton on one layer, and view the results on each layer with the different models.